# Поиск элемента в массиве

Tags: массивы, java

Как мне найти элемент массива начинающего с буквы а и чтоб в последствии этот элемент не выбирался

```
String[] names={"автомобиль","банка","велосипед","аквариум"}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
String[] names={"автомобиль","банка","велосипед","аквариум"}; 
for (String s:names) { 
   if(s.startsWith("a") {
      System.out.println("Bingo!");
      continue;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String[]names={"автомобиль","банка","велосипед","аквариум"};
for (int i = 0; i<names.length; i++) {
   if (names[i].charAt(0).equals("а")) continue;
// другие операции с нужными элементами
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) {
            if (names[i].charAt(0) == 'а') {
                System.out.println(names[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: так не правильно, твой код будет останавливать цикл при первом попадании на "а"